# JQuery Session PlugIn error JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use read /write to session using [Jquery Session plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.session.js)  on my asp.net webform .I added

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.session.js"></script> to the top of my aspx page
```

I am using dropdownlist change in Jquery ,Trying to set session value as follows

```
 $("#MainContent_ddlRequest").change(function () {
     $.session.set('GroupName', 'xyz');
                alert($.session.get('GenGroupName'));
});
```

but I am getting the error `"0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference"`
How can I resolve this error

I  even tried like this as follows.But I am still getting the same error

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.session.set('time', new Date());
            alert($.session.get('time'));
});
```

Here is my entire  asp.net page source below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZKyCMgqniM/aldukh4YFosrxeF/cGpC1q4aFWjLdll/R" />
</div>

    <div>
    <input id="butSet" type="button" value="SET" />
         <input id="butGet" type="button" value="GET" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#butSet').click(function () {
             $.session.set('time', new Date());
         });

         $('#butGet').click(function () {
             alert($.session.get('time'));
         });

     });
     </script>
```

Comment: I'm getting no issues... http://jsfiddle.net/KhxUx/2/

Comment: added my entire asp.net page source in my post

Answer (score 1):

What's the URL you're accessing it from?  Without a leading `/` in your Script URL, you're probably 404'ing on trying to load the script.

Best to do something like `src="<%=Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/...") %>"`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I tried changing path to <script src="<%=Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/jquery.session.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script> ,But I am still getting the same error

Comment: Can you post your entire output (view source) to jsfiddle or pastebin or the likes?  Or edit your post and put it there?  Need more context please.

Comment: added my entire asp.net page source in my post

Comment: I don't see the session script being included anywhere in your post or fiddle.

Comment: I tried with both scripts and I am getting the same error 1.https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.session.js                                    2.http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.js

Comment: You need both scripts and jquery must come before session. This is about all we can tell you at this point short of rewriting it for you. The fiddle is basically the solution. Dunno what else to offer, sorry